# $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_{50})$ via $\phi(11) = 3$ Then $\phi(x) = $? For any $x \in\Bbb Z_{50}$

Tags: group-theory

> $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_{50})$ via $\phi(11) = 3$ Then $\phi(x) = $? For any $x \in \Bbb Z_{50}$

The answer is $23x$ but I'm not quite sure how to figure that out. Here's what I did:

$\phi(11) = 3 \Rightarrow$ The function maps $11x \rightarrow 3x$ 
Adding $(11)^{-1} = 39$ (mod 50) on both sides gives us 
$x \rightarrow 42x$

What am I not doing correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$1\equiv -9\cdot11\pmod{50}\ .$$
Therefore,
$$\phi(x)\equiv\phi(-9x\cdot11)\equiv-9x\cdot\phi(11)\equiv-27x\equiv23x\pmod{50}\ .$$
In the second equivalence we used that $\phi(nx) = \phi(x)+\cdots+\phi(x) = n\phi(x)$.

---

Adding $39\equiv-11\pmod{50}$ to both sides just tells you that
$$\phi(11x)-11\equiv3x+39\ ,$$
which is no help at all.

Comment: Shouldn't the second equivalence be $-9 \phi(x) \cdot \phi(11)$?

Comment: @RobertShore No, the group structure is given by addition, not multiplication.

Comment: Sir how $30\equiv-11\pmod{50}$?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi It should be a $39$, thanks for spotting the typo. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Any automorphism $\phi$ of $\Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z$ is determined by $\phi(1)$ because $\phi(n) = n \phi(1)$, so it suffices to determine $\phi(1)$.  As noted by Daniel Robert-Nicoud, $1 \equiv -9 \cdot 11 \pmod{50}$, so $\phi(1) = -9 \phi(11) = -9 \cdot 3 = -27 ~(\mod 50) = 23$ and $\phi(n) = n \phi(1) = 23n$.